# Typescript error "An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements." while extending typescript definitions

Tags: typescript

I have downloaded the type definition of a module, let's say **ModuleA**, from `@types/module-a`.

The **module-a.d.ts** file looks like

```
declare module "module-a" {
  export = moda;
}

declare namespace moda {
  interface MODAPromise<T> {
    isResolved(): boolean;
    ....;
  }
}
```

Now, in my application, I find that I need to extend these types with some additional specifications.

Following advice received earlier, I build in my src directory a file **module-a.augmented.d.ts** such at this

```
declare module "module-a" {
    export interface MODAPromise {
        myNewProperty: any;
    }
}
```

If I do so though, TypeScript signals an error ***"An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements."***  in line

```
export = moda;
```

of **module-a.d.ts**. 
Is there a way to extend such type of declaration without having to touch the original **module-a.d.ts** file?

Answer (score 24):

I found that I could combine `export =` syntax with `namespace` to export types from the interface. `export =` is necessary (as far as I understand) to indicate that an external module uses CommonJS-style `exports` rather than ES6 exports. If you try to both use `export =` and `export` in the same module, you will receive the following error:

> TS2309: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.

However, if you declare a declare a namespace with the same name as the variable used in the `exports =` expression, you can place types inside of that namespace, making them accessible to consuming modules.

Here is an example of a module type definition using this technique:

```
declare module 'some-module' {
  namespace SomeClass {
    export interface IMyInterface {
      x:string;
    };
  }
  class SomeClass {
    constructor(p:SomeClass.IMyInterface);
  }
  export = SomeClass;
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful!

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to import `IMyInterface` in another file because the namespace `SomeClass` isn't exported.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you **set the export** to namespace moda in "module-a" that is defined in module-a.d.ts, and also **export MODAPromise** in "module-a" that is defined in module-a.augmented.d.ts.

Therefore, the "module-a" you're attempting to define looks like this:

```
declare module "module-a" {
    export = moda;
    export interface MODAPromise {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You're attempting to set the export, and export something else at the same time, which makes no sense. You need to find another way to export moda's MODAPromise and the augmented MODAPromise in the same time.

Comment: It looks like I can not do much without touching the code of module-a.d.ts file, which being downloaded from @types I would prefer not to touch. Am I right?

Comment: Why not? That's the whole point of open source. Feel free to contribute! Just fork the repository and open a pull request once you're done implementing it in your forked repository.

Comment: From your answer I don't understand how to use both export assignment and export types at the same time. Thus, this doesn't seem to be an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: I agree, this isn't an actual answer, but I hinted his mistake.