# Export assignment and exporting types in TypeScript ambient module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to add types for the [`config`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) module specific to our app.  The `config` module is dynamically generated from a JSON file so it's tricky to type.  Since it's a node module, I'm using an [ambient module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) for the typings.

```js
// config.d.ts
declare module 'config' {
  interface AppConfig {
    name: string;
    app_specific_thing: string;
  }
  const config: AppConfig;
  export = config;
}
```

How do I also export `AppConfig` so I can use it as a type like so:

```js
import * as config from 'config';

const appConfig: config.AppConfig;
```

#### Attempts

- If I export AppConfig directly in the `config` module it errors with:

  > TS2309: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.
- If I move `AppConfig` to another file (e.g. `./app_config`) to hold the exports and import them into `config.d.ts` it errors with:

  > TS2439: Import or export declaration in an ambient module declaration cannot reference module through relative module name.
- If I put the `AppConfig` export in the same file, but outside the `config` module, it errors with:

  > TS2665: Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'config' resolves to an untyped module at $PROJ/config/lib/config.js, which cannot be augmented.

This is similar to [Typescript error "An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements." while extending typescript definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708410/typescript-error-an-export-assignment-cannot-be-used-in-a-module-with-other-exp) with the requirement that I want to be able to import `AppConfig` as a type directly in other TS files.

Comment: do you really need to import it by the name `AppConfig`? I tried importing `* as config` and using `type AppConfig = typeof config`, which worked, so that's a workaround at least

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer requires a confusing Typescript concept:

[Declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) - the compiler merges two separate declarations declared with the same name into a single definition.  In this case, we create two declarations of `config`.

```
// config.d.ts
declare module 'config' {

  // This nested namespace 'config' will merge with the enclosing 
  // declared namespace 'config'.
  // https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html
  namespace config {
    interface AppConfig {
      name: string;
      app_specific_thing: string;
      my_enum: FakeEnum;
    }

    interface MyInterface {}

    // See side note below
    type FakeEnum = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
  }

  const config: AppConfig;
  export = config;
}
```

You can use the imports like so:

```
import * as config from 'config';
import { FakeEnum, MyInterface } from 'config';
```

As a side note, you cannot use `enums` with an [ambient module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) (the `declare module 'config'`) because enums compile to a JS object and you can't add new object to a module you don't control. You can work around the issue by faking an enum with a union type:

```
type FakeEnum = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for cases where you are augmenting a node-module at a file path. E.g. `declare module 'something/lib/util' {...}`. This is because it's impossible to use a file path as an ordinary namespace identifier.

Comment: @AustinDavis But you can follow the same structure as the types you want to augment. Look at the original file and then copy the entire outer structure, such as `global` or `namespace`, etc.